# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when using jest and parcel

Tags: typescript, jestjs, parcel, babel-jest

I use parcel for bundling and jest has a problem with following line:

```
import html from "./treeComponent.html"
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Because the html file has

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="treeComponent.css" />
```

Same goes if I only have a  or a comment containning a "<"

This is my jest.config:

```
module.exports = {
    roots: [
        "source"
    ],
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    verbose: false,
    collectCoverage: false
};
```

My .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "parcel watch source/* --no-hmr --out-dir ../wwwroot"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "since 2017-06"
  ]
}
```

I don't use any framework like angular or react.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it with jests [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) config. (in `jest.config.js`)

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  "\\.png$": "<rootDir>/tests/assets/empty_string.js",
  "my_specific_html_asset\\.html$": "<rootDir>/tests/assets/my_specific_html_asset.js",
  "\\.html$": "<rootDir>/tests/assets/html_generic_div.js"
},
```

`empty_string.js` contains:

```
export default '';
```

`my_specific_html_asset.js` contains:

```
export default '<div id="my_specific_id" class="my_specific_class"></div>';
```

`html_generic_div.js` contains:

```
export default '<div></div>';
```

In the docs, they mentioned `GlobalImageStub` but I could not get it to work, thus I used the empty string solution.